# How to make constructor name displayed instead 'Object'?

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
function F1 () { return {}; }
function F2 () { }

[F1(), new F2()]; // [Object, F2]
```

I need to the behavior of F1 was similar to F2 without new command - [F1, F2].

Comment: What do you mean "similar"? Do you want it to show `[F1, F2]` which is just plain wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's a browser & console version description dependable.
This is what you'll get, for instance, on an IE10 console from the same code of yours:

```
function F1 () { return {}; }; 
function F2 () { };

[F1(), new F2()]; 

>> [object Object],[object Object] {
    0 : [object Object],
    1 : [object Object]
}
```

Comment: ok. But how to get same result in Chrome: [F1, F2] without 'new' command?

Comment: You cant affect the browser console object item description and  that's it. And your request is nonsensical because F1 and F2 are different objects.

Answer (score 3):

you are return object `{}` in calling F1 ,that's true !!!..But if u want `I need to the behavior of F1 was similar to F2.`

```
function F1 () { return this;} //or {}
function F2 () { return this;} //or {}

[new F1(), new F2()]; // [F1,F2]
```

Answer (score 1):

constructor in javascript is just object and those can be initialized with `new` keyword. So, `F1()` is just a function call and `new F2()` is a way to create new object/s.

You can see:

```
function F1 () { return {}; } // <----not a constructor method
function F2 () { } // <---------------This can be a constructor method
```

`F1()` is not a constructor method in here because it has a return value as an object. You can't have a constructor which has a return value.

While `F2()` don't have a return value so that can be used as a constructor.

Comment: Why can `F1` not be a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `toString` method.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: This does not seem to influence the behavior in the chrome console.